# Want to enable image button based on the value in the Gridview Field

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

In Gridview i am using image button that Want to enable  based  on the value in the Field. My Partial Code is ..

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_delete" **Enabled='<%# Eval("fld_status").ToString()=="1" ?    "False" : "True" %>**' runat="server" ToolTip="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Important Alert : Do you delete this item ?')" CommandName="del" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("fld_id") %>' />
```

Comment: If fld_status = 1 means ,i want to  set  Enable ="False" for Image Button.

Comment: have you tried doing this in your DataItemBounded event for your gridview??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

via `RowDataBound` (which i prefer):

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        int status = (int)row["fld_status"];
        Button btn_delete = (Button) e.Row.FindControl("btn_delete");
        btn_delete.Enabled = status != 1; 
    }
}
```

from aspx:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_delete" runat="server"
    Enabled='<%# ((int)Eval("fld_status") !=1) ? true : false  %>' 
    ToolTip="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Important Alert : Do you delete this item ?')" CommandName="del" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("fld_id") %>' 
/>
```

Comment: Would the second one work? - _The server tag is not well formed_

Comment: From aspx:  CS0019: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Comment: @codingbiz: Corrected, that's the reason why i always use `RowDataBound`.

Comment: @bharathi You should use RowDataBound from codebehind - it is cleaner

Comment: Thanks but   If it is worked in aspx means easy to change. still it showing error   Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @bharathi: I have tested the code, it works for me. What type is `fld_status` in your DataSource? Modify it accordingly in `((int)Eval("fld_status") !=1)`. If it's a string you could use this code: `((string)Eval("fld_status") != "1")`

Comment: Integer only but its working fine while change decimal. Thanks Tim