# Disable grid delete button if already deleted

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Want to enable image button based on the value in the Gridview Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722395/want-to-enable-image-button-based-on-the-value-in-the-gridview-field)

I want to disable the gridview delete button if the status=1. 1 means already deleted.I am using the below code to disable the delete button it returns the error message "The server tag is not well formed.".

```
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px" HeaderImageUrl="~/images/icn_trash.png" >
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_delete" runat="server" Enabled="<%# (Eval("fld_status").ToString()=="0") ? "true" : "false" %>" ToolTip="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Important Alert : Do you delete this item ?')" CommandName="del" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("fld_val_id") %>' ImageUrl="~/images/icn_trash.png" />
   </ItemTemplate>
  <ItemStyle Width="20px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13722395/284240

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the quotes

```
Enabled="<%# (Eval(\"fld_status\").ToString()=="0") ? "true" : "false" %>"
```

you could also use single quotes like you did here

```
CommandArgument='<%#Bind("fld_val_id") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you should use `'` here:

```
Enabled='<%# (Eval("fld_status").ToString()=="0") ? "true" : "false" %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `"` with `'` and remove the `""` around the booleans:

```
Enabled='<%# (Eval("fld_status").ToString()=="0") ? true : false %>'
```